# Windows Store Apps : Loading styles from a customcontrol class library via reflection, OnApplyTemplate is not called?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, xamlparseexception

I am trying to load a custom control library via reflection in windows 8 Metro C# App, the library is loaded but the styles specified in generic.xaml are not loaded, eventually I tried to load the generic.xaml by making it as an Embedded resource and ,then extracted the Generic.xaml to a location and specified the location of it as uri of a ResourceDictionary object, but it throws an error

```
"Failed to create a 'System.Type' from the text local:CustomControl1"
```

I cannot create a nuget package or extension SDK as unfortunately that is not my requirement, 
Below sample code I wrote to copy the generic.xaml and load it in a resource dictionary

```
public sealed class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl1);
        Assembly CurrentAssembly = typeof(CustomControl1).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var names = CurrentAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
        var stream = CurrentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(names.First());
        //generic.xaml is an embedded resource in the current assembly
        if (stream != null)
        {
            //created new generic.xaml here
            var file = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Generic.xaml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting).Completed = (o, a) =>
            {
                var storageFile = o.GetResults();

                var s = storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync().Result;

                var length = (int)stream.Length;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
                int output = stream.Read(bytes, 0, length);

                s.Write(bytes, 0, length);
                s.Flush();
                s.Dispose();

                var asyncResult = this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    var resourceDict = new ResourceDictionary();
                    var uri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/" + storageFile.Name);
                    resourceDict.Source = uri;
                });
            };
        }
    }


    // OnApplyTemplate is not called without loading the style from generic.xaml
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

The below code I wrote in the custom control library's constructor, so that the control template can be set without generic.xaml

Here since the attribute TargeType="local:CustomControl1" is not present the control gets loaded properly, here since I loaded the style in the constructor, the OnApplyTemplate gets called

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"<ControlTemplate  
xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""   
xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""  
xmlns:d=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008""
xmlns:mc=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"">");
sb.Append(@"<Border Background=""{TemplateBinding 
Background}""                                                             
BorderBrush=""{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}""
BorderThickness=""{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"">
   <Grid>
      <Button x:Name=""Tbx1"" Content=""Hello World"" Foreground=""HotPink""   
       HorizontalAlignment=""Stretch"" VerticalAlignment=""Stretch""/>
  </Grid>
</Border>");
sb.Append(@"</ControlTemplate>");
this.Template = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Load(sb.ToString());
```

but the problem is loading all the styles using XamlReader is not a good idea, unless we are out of Options. As there may be various dependent styles which too have to be loaded.

Comment: I notice that you are creating a `ResourceDictionary`, but don't seem to be using it anywhere. It also seems to me that where you are loading the style (and getting the error), you are not defining the `local` namespace properly. I'm still not sure why you would need to be loading the control like this. Is it part of your requirement to do it this way? Or could you change to something more similar to the answer I posted?

Comment: A section of my resource dictionary is shown below

Comment: As you see my namespace is defined properly                                                                <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyControlsNameSpace">
    <Style TargetType="local:MyControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
                    <Border

Comment: In Generic.xaml following xaml is placed to merge the dictionary as you suggested

Comment: <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary
            Source="ms-appx:///MyControl.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

Comment: I had changed my code according to your suggestion, it works in normal case that is when we reference control library directly to our solution without reflection, but my requirement is to load the controls from library by reflection, Here in reflection we load the Assembly and try to create an instance of the control class, so when we try to create controls using this way I get an error "Failed to create system.Type from" as when the MyControl.xaml gets loaded it does not recognize the new type of custom control being registered since it is new type of control which was not previously register

Answer (score 1):

Check out how they do it in the [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Themes/Generic.xaml). They create the `Generic.xaml` for the project and include all control templates inside of separate styles in different `ResourceDictionary`s packaged next to the respective controls.

To put it more simply (for Templated controls, like you are using):

- Make two files for each control, `MyControl.cs` and `MyControl.xaml`
- In `MyControl.cs` in your `MyControl` constructor, set the `StyleKey` to be `typeof(MyControl)` (like you are doing currently).
- Make sure there is a style for your control with `TargetType` set to the type of your control. Do the same thing for the `ControlTemplate` that you have as the `Template` property set in the `Style`.
- In `MyControl.xaml`, make a `ResourceDictionary` that stores all of the necessary styles, templates, and resources.
- In your `Generic.xaml`, create a `MergedDictionaries` tag under the root and create a `ResourceDictionary` for each control, setting the Source to the full path of `MyControl.xaml`

Set each of the .xaml files to be build type of `Page` with `CustomTool` set to `MSBuild:Compile`.

Hope this helps and Happy coding!

Comment: Assembly assem = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("MyControlAssembly"));
            Type CType = assem.ExportedTypes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "MyControl");
            object ob = Activator.CreateInstance(CType);
            //here t grid is a grid object in the MainPage.xaml of the current project
            tgrid.Children.Add(ob as FrameworkElement);

Comment: It still gives the same exception "Failed to create a 'System.Type' from the text local:MyControl"

Comment: The only difference between winrttoolkit and my code is , i am loading the control assembly via reflection in my project , as shown in above code.